# Появление блока из-за пределов экрана jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

```js
jQuery(function(f) {
    $(".hidden").animate({"left": "100px", "opacity": "show"}, "slow");

});
```

```html
<div class="content__item hidden">
  <div class="content__item__pic">
    <img src="img/pc.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Сетка сверстана на основе bootstrap. И нужно чтобы блок выезжал из-за пределов экрана, а не из-за пределов контейнера бутстрапа.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вот так хотели? Просто ваш код был не полным. Если что то упустил то дополните вопрос.

```js
jQuery(function(f) {
  $(".hidden").animate({"left": "100px", "opacity": "1"}, "slow");

});
```

```css
.content__item__pic img{
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
.hidden{
  position: fixed;
  left: -100px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content__item hidden">
   <div class="content__item__pic"><img src="http://www.primesiteweb.com/files/design/web-programming-detail.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Вот другой вариант ответа со скроллом.

```js
jQuery(function(f) {
  var img_center = ($(window).width() - $(".hidden").width())/2;
  $(window).bind('scroll', function(event){
    if($(this).scrollTop() <= 300){
      var op = $(this).scrollTop()/300;
      var lft = $(this).scrollTop()/300*(img_center);
      $(".hidden").css({"left": lft+'px', "opacity": op});
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content__item__pic img{
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
.hidden{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.red{
  color: red;
}
.green{
  color: green;
}
.blue{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p class="red">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p class="green">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p class="blue">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p class="red">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p class="green">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p class="blue">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content__item hidden">
   <div class="content__item__pic">
    <img src="http://www.primesiteweb.com/files/design/web-programming-detail.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: что-то похожее)) только класс hidden изначально скрыт (display: none). Нужно чтобы при прокрутке страницы. этот элемент выезжал на центр.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас так покажу вам, но не важно что бы он был `display: none`, Элемент можно скрыть по разному.

Comment: @user270248 уточнить можете сколько скролить страницу что бы блок достиг центра?

Comment: скролить на 300px

Comment: @user270248 Посмотрите, добавил новый вариант, со скроллом.